# I am calling an event listener on a button and it wont create the html element in my DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I have some `<li>` tags under a `<ul>` in my HTML code. These `<li>` are
styled with CSS to create cards with a title and description.

I have created a button with an event listener that I wish to create a
new `<li>` element under the `<ul>` tag in the HTML when I press the
button.

I retrieve the `<ul>` and attempt to `appendChild()` with a new `<li>`.
This is all within a class in JS. I am not sure why the new `<li>` cards are not being displayed when I press the button.

````
```     
    
     class DOMHelper {
      static clearEventListeners(element) {
        const clonedElement = element.cloneNode(true);
        element.replaceWith(clonedElement);
        return clonedElement;
      }
    
    
  //receives element ID and a New destination in the DOM and sends the 
    //card to that destination Via Append.
      static moveElement(elementId, newDestinationSelector) {
        const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        const destinationElement = 
    document.querySelector(newDestinationSelector);
        destinationElement.append(element);
      }
    }
    
    class Tooltip {}
    
    class ProjectItem {
      constructor(id, updateProjectListsFunction, type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.updateProjectListsHandler = updateProjectListsFunction;
        this.connectMoreInfoButton();
        this.connectSwitchButton(type);
      }
    
      connectMoreInfoButton() {}
    
    
      //retreives the button of the given DOM element and adds an event 
      //listener to it that executes updateProjectListHandler
      //recieves from: update () {}
      //runs updateProjectListsHandler --> this.switchProject --> 
      
  connectSwitchButton(type) {
        const projectItemElement = document.getElementById(this.id);
        let switchBtn = projectItemElement.querySelector('button:last-of- 
   type');
        switchBtn = DOMHelper.clearEventListeners(switchBtn);
        switchBtn.textContent = type === 'active' ? 'Finish' : 'Activate';
        switchBtn.addEventListener(
          'click', 
          this.updateProjectListsHandler.bind(null, this.id)
        );
      }
    
      update(updateProjectListsFn, type) {
        this.updateProjectListsHandler = updateProjectListsFn;
        this.connectSwitchButton(type);
      }
    }
    
    class ProjectList {
      projects = [];
    
      constructor(type) {
        //selects all of the li elements under the `#${type}-projects DOM 
        //element depending on the element input type 
        //and creates a new ProjectItem for every li element it found. 
        this.type = type;
        const prjItems = document.querySelectorAll(`#${type}-projects 
       li`);
        for (const prjItem of prjItems) {
          this.projects.push(
            new ProjectItem(prjItem.id, this.switchProject.bind(this), 
    this.type)
          );
        }
       
        //new DayOfWeek('Monday');
        console.log(this.projects);
      }
    
      setSwitchHandlerFunction(switchHandlerFunction) {
        this.switchHandler = switchHandlerFunction;
      }
    
    
      //pushes project to the projects array. Project input is "new 
    //ProjectList('finished');"
      addProject(project) {
        this.projects.push(project);
        DOMHelper.moveElement(project.id, `#${this.type}-projects ul`);
        project.update(this.switchProject.bind(this), this.type);
      }
    
      //finds every project id in projects with the id matching constant 
      //projectId
      //filters out every dom object with id that does not equal the 
      //projected input to the function
      switchProject(projectId) {
        // const projectIndex = this.projects.findIndex(p => p.id === 
    projectId);
        // this.projects.splice(projectIndex, 1);
        this.switchHandler(this.projects.find(p => p.id === projectId));
        this.projects = this.projects.filter(p => p.id !== projectId);
        console.log('Testing this button')
      }
    
    
      switchDayHandler() {
        const selectDayOfWeek = document.getElementById('p4');
        //const dayOfWeek = selectDayOfWeek.querySelector('li')
        selectDayOfWeek.addEventListener(
          'click',
          this.updateDayInfoHandler()
        );
        console.log(selectDayOfWeek);
      }
    
      updateDayInfoHandler () {
        console.log('TEST TEST TEST');
    
      }
    
    }
    
    class DayOfWeek {
    
    projectList = {
      monday: [
        {
          title: 'test',
          description: "test"
        }
      ]
    }
    
    
    constructor(day) {
    
    this.createNewButton;
    
    
    
          switch (day) {
              case ( 'Monday' ):
                //this.addNewListItemHandler();   
                  break;
              case ( 'Tuesday' ):      
                console.log('Tuesday');
                  break;
              case ( 'Wednesday' ):
                console.log('Wednesday');
                  break;
              case ( 'Thursday' ):
                console.log('Thursday');
                  break;
              case ( 'Friday' ):
                  console.log('Friday');
                  break;
              //default:
                //  ingredient = null;
          }
         
      }
    
    
    
    addNewListItemHandler() {
          
          const projectItem = document.getElementById('active');
          const newListItem = document.createElement('li');
          newListItem.innerHTML = `id="p2"
          data-extra-info="Not really a business topic but still 
          important."
          class="card"
          >
                <h2>MONDAY ITEM</h2>
                <p>Don't forget to pick up groceries today.</p>
                <button class="alt">More Info</button>
                <button>Finish</button>
                `;
          projectItem.appendChild(newListItem);
      }
    
      createNewButton() {
        const newButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
        newButton.addEventListener( 'click', this.addNewListItemHandler);
      
      }
    
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    class App {
      static init() {
        const activeProjectsList = new ProjectList('active');
        const finishedProjectsList = new ProjectList('finished');
        
        activeProjectsList.setSwitchHandlerFunction(
          finishedProjectsList.addProject.bind(finishedProjectsList)
        );
        finishedProjectsList.setSwitchHandlerFunction(
          activeProjectsList.addProject.bind(activeProjectsList)
        );
      }
    }

    App.init();

   ```

    <body>
  
    <header id="main-header">
      <h1>Project Planner</h1>
    </header>

    <div>
    <section id="days-projects">
      <header>
        <h2>Days</h2>
      </header>
      <ul>
        <li
          id="p4"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but 
          still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Monday</h2>
        </li>
        <li
          id="p5"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but 
           still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Tuesday</h2>
        </li>
        <li
          id="p6"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but 
          still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Wednesday</h2>
        </li>
        <li
          id="p7"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but 
          still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Thursday</h2>
        </li>
        <li
          id="p8"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but 
          still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Friday</h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="active-projects">
      <header>
        <h2>Active Projects</h2>
      </header>
      <ul id = 'active'>
        <li
          id="p1"
          data-extra-info="Got lifetime access, but would be nice to 
          finish it soon!"
       class="card"
        >
          <h2>Finish the Course</h2>
          <p>Finish the course within the next two weeks.</p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Finish</button>
        </li>
        <li
          id="p2"
          data-extra-info="Not really a business topic but still 
          important."
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Buy Groceries</h2>
          <p>Don't forget to pick up groceries today.</p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Finish</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </section>

     <section id="finished-projects">
      <header>
        <h2>Finished Projects</h2>
      </header>
      <ul>
        <li
          id="p3"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but 
          still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Book Hotel</h2>
          <p>
            Academind conference takes place in December, don't forget to 
            book a hotel.
          </p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Activate</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </section>

   

     </div>
    
      <button id = "addButton" class='add_Button'>ADD NEW</button>
    
    < /body>
    </html>

    ```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    #main-header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 6rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: #a3d2ca;
    }

    #main-header h1 {
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
    }

    footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    li {
      margin: 1rem 0;
      
    }

    section {
      margin: 1rem auto;
      width: 40rem;
      max-width: 90%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      
      
    }

    section ul {
      padding: 1rem;
      max-height: 30rem;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    .Days {
      padding: 1rem;
      max-height: 20rem;
      
      background: #d49a89;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      /*border: 1px solid #ff0062;*/
      margin: 0;
    }

    section > h2 {
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    button {
      font: inherit;
      background: #f7d1ba;
      color: white;
      border: 1px solid #f7d1ba;
      padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button.alt {
      background: white;
      color: #ff0062;
    }

    button:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    button:hover,
    button:active {
      background: #f7d1ba;
      border-color: #5eaaa8;
      color: white;
    }

    .card {
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
      padding: 1rem;
      background: white;
      
    }

    #active-projects {
      border: 2px solid #d49a89;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 30%;
      border-radius: 10px;

    }

    #active-projects > header {
      background: #d49a89;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #active-projects header h2 {
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #finished-projects {
      border: 2px solid #d49a89;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 30%;
      border-radius: 10px;

    }

    #finished-projects > header {
      background: #d49a89;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #finished-projects header h2 {
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 35rem;
      
      
    }


    #days-projects {
      border: 2px solid #d49a89;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 30%;
      border-radius: 10px;


    }

    #days-projects > header {
      background: #d49a89;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #days-projects header h2 {
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #days-projects li:hover {
      background: #5eaaa8;
    }

    .add_Button {
      align-items: center;
      border: solid red;
    }
 ```
````

Comment: you are creating another `<li></li>` inside an `<li>` tag?

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS associated with this - seems central to the issue perhaps

Comment: Ok I will add. Thanks! and If it seems I am creating another  <li> within an <li> than that is not my intention. I simply want to create one within the <ul>

Comment: Are you instantiating the DayOfWeek class anywhere?

Comment: No I am not? Where would be the correct place to do this? I think that may be the issue...

Comment: Yep, unless you instantiate it, none of your code here will run.

Comment: I added the full code, but the issue I am having is mainly at the bottom and instantiating it. I am going to research more on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting something to appear now after trying the suggestions. It's not exactly right...some of it is raw unformatted code but at least it is appearing upon pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there may be multiple problems (as @CodeCreate mentions, you are adding an li inside an li, and I'm not sure why you would call createNewButton twice), but I suspect the main issue you're asking about is with your addEventListener call.

You need to pass addEventListener a function to run when the event fires.

You're trying to pass this.addNewListItemHandler, but because you have added parentheses at its end, you are invoking the function immediately, rather than attaching it to run when the button is clicked.

Try rewriting your createNewButton method as:

newButton.addEventListener(
'click',
this.addNewListItemHandler
);

Comment: I tried to use newButton.addEventListener( 'click', this.addNewListItemHandler ); but this still did not work. I will keep trying. Its weird...even if I try to console.log() something instead of calling a function on the button...that still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating the class after it's defined:

let daysOfWeek = new DaysOfWeek

It's probable that this doesn't need to be a class to begin with, but since that's more a design decision, I'll leave that for you to research and decide.

Comment: I was also wondering if it needed to be in a class. I was using classes to practice OOP but this may be an instance where it's not needed I will try your recommendation. Thanks!